# Number of different terms in multinomial expansion

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find the number of each "kind" of terms in the expansion of the following
$$(x_1+ \dots+x_n)^k$$
A simple test for small $n$ and $k$ got me the number of all terms as
$${n+k-1 \choose k-1}$$
and clearly we have $n$ terms of the form $x_i^k$. I want to know how many terms have at least one variable of order $1$, eg $x_1 x_2^2 x_3^2 x_4$
not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

I think this requires a combination of [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) and [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  You have computed the number of ways to distribute $k$ balls in $n$ bins, as given by stars and bars. If some bin must have exactly $1$ ball, there are $\binom n1$ ways to choose which bin it will be, and then we must distribute the remaining $k-1$ balls in the other $n-1$ bins.  By stars and bars, there are $\binom{n+k-3}{n-2}$ ways to do this, giving $$\binom n1\binom{n+k-3}{n-2}$$ possibilities.  However, any configuration with two bins having one ball has been counted twice, so we must subtract these.  There are $\binom n2$ choice for the two bins, and then we must distribute the remaining $k-2$ balls into the other $n-2$ bins.  Once we've computed this, every configuration with $3$ one-ball bins has been counted $3$ times, and subtracted $3$ times, so we must add it back in, and so on.

Altogether, we get
$$\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}\binom nj\binom{n+k-2j-1}{n-j-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The terms with exactly one $x_1$ in are given by:

$$x_1(x_2+\dots+x_n)^{k-1}$$

but this might contain terms with only one $x_2$ in say.

You then need to use Inclusion-Exclusion to get the complete answer.

$$[x_1x_2]=\operatorname{NT}[k(k-1)(x_3+\dots+x_n)^{k-2}]$$

where $[]$ is 'coefficient of' and $\operatorname{NT}$ is 'Number of Terms'.

etc...